# How do I use a plugin to swap out the template file for a custom post type?

Tags: plugin-development, templates

I'm trying to apply a filter for a custom post type and give it a different template. All from within a plugin. However, despite confirming that `add_hooks()` is called (everything else works in that area), the filter is flatly ignored.

I can only guess that I got something wrong as it looks like the filter is never applied. I know it is not because I put an `else/die` in there. It should either give me my template or die (right?) but it ignores me. How do I do this correctly?

```
class some_cool_new_stuff{

   public function __construct(){
       $this->add_hooks();
   }

   public function page_template( $page_template ) {
       if ( is_page( 'my_lovely_post_type' ) ) {
           $page_template = MY_CUSTOM_CONST_FOR_PLUGIN_DIR . 'templates/business-page.php'; // this does not happen but the path is 100% correct
       }else{
          die("Help me, I'm going to die!!"); // this never happens
       }
       return $page_template; 
   }

   public function add_hooks(){
       // ... 
       add_action( 'init', array($this,'awesome_function') );
       add_filter( 'page_template', array($this,'page_template') );
       // ... 
   }

   // ...

}
```

Here is some other stuff that doesn't work for me:

```
    add_filter( 'my_lovely_post_type_template', array($this,'page_template') );
    add_filter( 'template_include', array($this,'page_template') );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a whole bunch of filter possibilities, I found one that worked.

```
add_filter( 'single_template', array($this,'page_template') );
```

Which got my function to be called. However, I also needed to make some more changes (not least of which taking out the `die` line). This was, finally, what worked:

```
public function page_template( $page_template ) {
    global $post;
    if ( 'my_lovely_post_type' === $post->post_type ) {
        $page_template = BUSINESS_PAGE_PLUGIN_DIR . 'templates/business-page.php';
    }
    return $page_template;
}
```